# SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en python 3 y estoy haciendo un ejercicio para realizar un árbol de decisión por lo que ingrese la tabla a mano de la siguiente manera

ESTE ES EL CODIGO:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Outlook": ["Sunny", "Sunny", "Overcast", "Rain", "Rain", "Rain", "Overcast", "Sunny", 
    "Sunny", "Rain", "Sunny", "Overcast", "Overcast", "Rain"]
    "Temperature": ["Hot", "Hot", "Hot", "Mild", "Cool", "Cool", "Cool", "Mild", "Cool", 
    "Mild", "Mild", "Mild","Hot", "Mild"]
    "Humidity": ["High", "High", "High", "High", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "High", 
    "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "High", "Normal", "High"]
    "Windy": ["False", "True", "False", "False", "False", "True", "True", "False", "False", 
             "False", "True", "True", "False", "True"]
    "Play golf": ["No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
             "Yes", "Yes", "No"]
})
```

El error que me sale es:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

y lo marca en el primer corchete

Answer (score 0):

Te falta escribir una coma despues de cada par "string : lista".

```
data = pd.DataFrame({ 
    "Outlook": ["Sunny", "Sunny", "Overcast", "Rain", "Rain", "Rain", "Overcast", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Rain", "Sunny", "Overcast", "Overcast", "Rain"],
    "Temperature": ["Hot", "Hot", "Hot", "Mild", "Cool", "Cool", "Cool", "Mild", "Cool", "Mild", "Mild", "Mild","Hot", "Mild"],
    "Humidity": ["High", "High", "High", "High", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "High", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "High", "Normal", "High"], 
    "Windy": ["False", "True", "False", "False", "False", "True", "True", "False", "False", "False", "True", "True", "False", "True"], 
    "Play golf": ["No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"] 
})
```